# Replacing strings in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have some data in the format `\u00c2\u00a39.99` in my JavaScript/jQuery program.

How do I remove the `\u00c2\u00a3` and keep the `9.99`? So:

```
var price = "\u00c2\u00a39.99"
```

changes to

```
var newprice = "9.99"
```

Comment: Use [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to match that pattern:

```js
var test = "\u00c2\u00a39.99".match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0];
alert(test);
```

Comment: the code will be ? var newprice = price.replace(/\d+\.\d+/, "");

Comment: `var newprice = price.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0];`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8psm38by/ I want it to do it to this data provided in the link. Thanks so far. @brso05

Comment: @Legria your `Object` contains a `String`.